# Trouble retrieving ParseUser Object in android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Hello i'm new to parse and created a friendship table successfully. Now i am trying to retrieve a Parseuser A who has requested to be a friend with ParseUser B. But i'm receiving an error saying `java.lang.IllegalStateException: ParseObject has no data for 'username'. Call fetchIfNeeded() to get the data.` Basically i retrieve the requesters information and try to display in in a listView as the User could decide to reject or accept the friendship. Please could someone tell me what i did wrong. I just want to display the requester info whenever a request has been sent to add a friend. Then userB has the option to accept or reject the request.

```
private void queryFriendShipRequest() {
       //retrieving requesters info to display on a list view
       ParseQuery<ParseObject> parseQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Friendship");
        parseQuery.whereEqualTo("accepterId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
        parseQuery.whereEqualTo("Status", "pending");
        parseQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    parseUserList.clear();
                    for (ParseObject parseObject : objects) {
                        parseUserList.add((FriendShip) parseObject);
                       // Log.d("FriendShip", parseUserList.toString());
                    }
                    updateFriendsList();
                }
                else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Unable to retreive Invites: " + e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        });
    }

private void updateFriendsList() {

         ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.friend_request_list, parseUserList) {

             @Override
             public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                 if(convertView==null) {
                     convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.friend_request_list, parent, false);
                 }

                 ProfilePictureView profilePictureView1 = (ProfilePictureView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.userProfileName11);
                 TextView textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.IDNameOfPerson);
                 Button button = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.accept);
                 Button button1 = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.reject);
                       profilePictureView1.setProfileId(parseUserList.get(position).getFrom().getString("UserId); //errors complaining it cannot retrieve parseuser
 textView.setText(parseUserList.get(position).getFrom().getUsername()); //errors complaining it cannot retrieve parseuser

                 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onClick(View v) {
                         acceptFriendRequest(position);
                     }
                 });

                 button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onClick(View v) {
                         //rejectFriendRequest(position);
                     }
                 });

                 return convertView;
             }

         };
        friendsList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

My error:

```
12-06 17:26:20.236  18468-18468/com.example.davchen.skibuddies E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.davchen.skibuddies, PID: 18468
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ParseObject has no data for 'username'. Call fetchIfNeeded() to get the data.
            at com.parse.ParseObject.checkGetAccess(ParseObject.java:3513)
            at com.parse.ParseObject.getString(ParseObject.java:3089)
            at com.parse.ParseUser.getUsername(ParseUser.java:373)
            at com.example.davchen.skibuddies.Fragments.ProfileTab$2.getView(ProfileTab.java:114)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2823)
            at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1290)
            at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1202)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1489)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2897)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2248)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1306)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1548)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1191)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6642)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. All i had to do was use the include to access the requesterId.

```
query.include("requesterId");
```